# tmux - unable to start any gui application

Tags: zsh, tmux

I am running Ubuntu-gnome 13.04. My default shell is zsh 5.0.0 and I usually run tmux 1.7 in the terminal 3.6.1.

In terminal, if I `evince` or `gedit`, the applications start as expected. I can append an &, too.

But if I start tmux and from tmux if I strat `evince` or `gedit`, it gives an error:

`(evince:19053): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: Could not open network socket`

How can I correct the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using Tmux under gnome. The thread here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=167029

Pointed me to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Tips_and_tricks

where adding the following to my ~/.bashrc file before the aliases fixed the problem.

```
# If not running interactively, do not do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```